# org source block in lowercase

Tags: org-mode

in org-mode when I type `<s TAB` it turns into:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC 

#+END_SRC
```

How can I configure it so it creates it in lowercase, e.g.:

```
#+begin_src 

#+end_src
```

Syntactically it's the same, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable that controls this is `org-structure-template-alist`, and I do this as follows:

```
(mapc (lambda (arg) (setcdr arg (list (downcase (cadr arg)))))
    org-structure-template-alist)
```

Perhaps there's a better way to do that (a setq and a mapcar, maybe?), but you get the gist.

Comment: This will downcase all the tab-expanded options, if you only want to change `#+BEGIN_SRC ...` to the lowercase version wrap `(setcdr arg ...)` in `(if (string= (car arg) "s") (setcdr arg ...))`

Comment: lowercasing all tab-expanded options is what I want. Thanks!

Comment: oh, inspecting the var I found <n for notes? But what that for? Why would anyone make a section of notes instead of having it as text or in a drawer?